# Find Distinct Values for same value in List C#

Tags: c#, list, linq, .net-core

I have a list which has `ordernumber`, `invoiceNumber` and `itemnumber` fields.

```
List<OrderDetail> lst=new List<OrderDetail>()
{
    new OrderDetail{
        ordernumber="O123",
        invoiceNumber="Inv123",
        itemnumber="I123"}
}

lst.Add(new OrderDetail(){
ordernumber="O123",
invoiceNumber="Inv124",
itemnumber="I145"
});

lst.Add(new OrderDetail(){
ordernumber="O456",
invoiceNumber="Inv125",
itemnumber="I145"
});

lst.Add(new OrderDetail(){
ordernumber="O456",
invoiceNumber="Inv125",
itemnumber="I145"
});
```

I want to find all orders having the same `ordernumber` but different `invoiceNumbers` and throw an error. How can we identify such records?

I used following code:

```
List<string> lstOrders=lst.select(x=>x.ordernumber).Distinct().ToList();
foreach(var order in lstOrders)
{
  List<string>lstInvoice = lst.where(x=>x.ordernumber==order).select(x=>invoiceNumber).Distinct().ToList();
   if(lstInvoice.Count >1)
   {
     throw;
   }
}
```

Is there any other efficient way?

Comment: Have you tried grouping?

Comment: What have you tried so far? is there any specific error/issue you faced while implementing this logic? Show some of your efforts

Comment: Also, did you use the wrong tag with `[core]` because I don't see anything in your question about CPU cores?

Comment: So duplicate ordernumber+invoicenumber are ok?

Comment: yes we have requirement same order number should have same invoice number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find all orders with multiple invoices, you could use this:

```
var duplicateOrdersWithDifferentInvoiceNumbers = lst
    .GroupBy(o => o.ordernumber)
    .Where(g => g.Select(o => o.invoiceNumber).Distinct().Count() > 1);
```

Comment: I think `DistinctBy` can make this even shorter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ GroupBy to group the orders by order number, then filter the groups that have more than one distinct invoice number.

```
var groups = lst.GroupBy(o => o.ordernumber);

foreach (var orderGroup in groups)
{
    var invoices = orderGroup.Select(o => o.invoiceNumber).Distinct();
    
    if (invoices.Count() > 1)
    {
       //do something else here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The core part is the same as Tim's answer, although I added the part where you could throw an exception for each order with different invoices.

```cs
var duplicates = lst.GroupBy(a => a.ordernumber)
    .Where(b => b.Select(c => c.invoiceNumber).Distinct().Count() > 1).ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < duplicates.Length; i++)
{
    var invoices = duplicates[i].Select(d => d.invoiceNumber);
    string report = $"Order numbered {duplicates[i].First().ordernumber} have different invoice numbers: {string.Join(", ", invoices)}.";
    Console.WriteLine(report);
}
```

With your example it would output:

> Order numbered O123 have different invoice numbers: Inv123, Inv124.